# In JS, why is what is supposed to be a function sometimes defined inside "< >"?

Tags: javascript

so please bear with me... :-)

I'm trying to understand how existing JS is working.  I see this....

```
const SqfPageWrap = (props) => <SqfPage {...props} flow='submit' />
```

I've read up on the arrow function and understand (believe) that the "const SqfPageWrap = (props) =>" piece is just a shorthand for...

```
const function SqfPageWrap (props) =
```

But in all the examples I've found googling the arrow function, the function definition that follows is inside curly braces....

```
const function SqfPageWrap (props) = {function code in here}
```

It appears that the function here is...

```
<SqfPage {..props} flow='submit' />
```

That doesn't look like a function to me.  It looks more like html.  Can anyone explain what's going on here ?

This code is being used in a "react" wrapper.  I don't know if that's important to know for this example.

Comment: This is not javascript, this is `JSX`.

Comment: That's not JavaScript. That's [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)

Answer (score 2):

React uses a special Javascript language extension called JSX, that lets you define HTML structures inside your Javascript.

So, if we examine this function that you're looking at:

```js
const SqfPageWrap = (props) => <SqfPage {...props} flow='submit' />
```

This is defining a function that returns the HTML element SqfPage, with certain attributes. The way you write this as a non-arrow function is as follows:

```js
function SqfPageWrap(props) {
  return <SqfPage {...props} flow='submit' />
}
```

Under the hood, JSX compiles down to a bunch of function calls that ultimately create an object, holding data about the HTML structure you defined in JSX. This object can then be used by React to actually insert HTML into the page, or modify the HTML in the page, etc.

See [this page](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) to learn more about jsx.

Comment: Thanks You Scotty !

So instead of returning something which might ultimately be used to generate html inside react, it's just providing the html (a shortcut).  Is that basically correct ?

Sorry for miscategorizing this as "javascript".

Comment: Conceptually, that's how it's supposed to feel. Technically, under the hood, it's just returning some object that React will ultimately use to generate the HTML.

Comment: (Also, it's still ok to call this Javascript, everyone does, because that's what it is. It's just important to recognize that it's not _just_ Javascript)